# Ruby on Rails: has_many through frustrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I'm having a frustrating problem with a has_many through: namely the fact that the through models are not created until save.   Unfortunately, I need to set data on these models prior to saving the parent.

Here's the loose setup:

```
class Wtf < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
  belongs_to :bar
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wtfs
  has_many :foos, :through => :wtfs
end


class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wtfs
  has_many :bars, :through => :wtfs

  def after_initialize
    Bar.all.each do |bar|
      bars << bar
    end
  end

end
```

Everything is fine except that I need to access the "wtf"'s prior to save:

> > f = Foo.new
> >     => #
> >
> > f.bars
> >     => [list of bars]

empty list here

> > f.wtfs
> >     => []
> >
> > f.save!
> >     => true

now I get stuff

> > f.wtfs
> >     => [list of stuff]

I even went so far as to explicitly create the wtfs doing this:

```
 def after_initialize
    Bar.all.each do |bar|
      wtfs << Wtf.new( :foo => self, :bar => bar, :data_i_need_to_set => 10)
    end
  end
```

This causes the f.wtfs to be populated, but not the bars.  When I save and retrieve, I get double the expected wtfs.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How is a Wtf supposed to be saved and associated with a Foo before the Foo is saved and given an ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have the right idea with creating the `Wtfs` directly.  I think it will turn out OK if you just set the bars at the same time:

```
def after_initialize
  Bar.all.each do |bar|
    wtfs << Wtf.new(:bar => bar, :data_i_need_to_set => 10)  # Rails should auto-assign :foo => self
    bars << bar
  end
end
```

Rails should save the records correctly because they are the same collection of objects.  The only drag might be that if rails doesn't have the smarts to check if a new `Bar` record in the bars collection *already* has a `Wtf` associated, it might create one anyway.  Try it out.

Comment: Thanks, yeah it was right, and I'll add your bit about assigning the bars there too

Here was the problem:
after_initialize will fire every time the Foo is instantiated, I only need it to fire when I create a new one.  So Ill be adding this to the start of the function.

return unless self.new_record?

Comment: Yeah, that might be your best bet for that style...  though I might suggest creating a class method on the model called `new_with_bars` that creates a new record and assigns the bars and wtfs

Comment: This is a really helpful method, but be careful, if you delete from `foo.bars`, it won't delete the associated `wtf`

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you write a `before_save` handler on Wtf that would set the data you need to set? It would have access to both the foo and bar, if needed.

Comment: Yeah this would work, but I need to display the Wtf data for the use to override.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the method that populates bar to an after_create, like this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wtfs
  has_many :bars, :through => :wtfs
  after_create :associate_bars

  def associate_bars
    Bar.all.each do |bar|
      bars << bar
    end
  end
end
```

This would make the wtfs be already be created when this method is called.

Comment: I tried using after_create, this only seemed to fire after I did a foo.save.  Right after Foo.new I want to display Wtf data and allow the user to mess with

Comment: Also, I really like your idea of creating an "associate_bars" method, I'm definitely implementing that.  It's a lot cleaner than what I had.